# Find out total number of cores on a Win Server 2008 cluster system

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is there a way to find out the total number of cores available on Server 2008 cluster system? i.e. total number of cores on all compute nodes? Is there an environment variable that has this information?

Thanks,

AG

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the .NET framework, you can use the Environment Class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx

**EDIT:**

Note, this gets the number of cores on an individual server, not a cluster.

Comment: Thank You. However it looks like this returns the number of processors on the current computer only. Is there a way to get the total number of cores that are available on the entire cluster system?

Comment: You're right, sorry I overlooked the "cluster" part. I'm not sure, unfortunately. You might want to try asking this question on serverfault.com too.